# Can you go to a Conference in Canada on a Visitor Visa, or only a Business one?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada, conferences

As far as I can tell from the [Visit Canada official website section on visas](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/index.asp), there are three main kinds approvals for non-Canadians making a short trip: [eTA](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/eta.asp) (for visa-waiver nationals coming by air), Visitor Visas and Business Visas

For someone who isn't from a visa-waiver country (eg an Indian citizen living in India), who wants to attend a Conference (in this case a few day event on a specific open source project), what kind of visa do you need?

Some bits of the [Visit Canada official website section on visas](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/index.asp) talks about Visitor Visas or Business Visas, other parts talk about Tourist Visas and Business Visas, which is proving confusing (at least for me and my Indian friend...). The [Business Visa sub-section](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/business.asp) does mention conferences as being something you can do on a business visa, but also they look harder to get. The [Tourist Visa sub-section](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/tourist.asp) that you confusingly turn up on after clicking many of the Visitor Visa links doesn't seem to say anything about what you can and can't do on a tourist visa. The [tourist visa page](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/index.asp) links to a Visitor Visa application form, again leading me to be confused.

(A quick google with likely keywords only found me information on what Canadians going to the USA for conferences should / shouldn't say to US immigration about their trip...)

So, hopefully simple question - Someone from a visa country (eg India) travelling to Canada to attend a conference, but who isn't doing it as a work trip (they're paying personally), what kind of visa do they need to apply for? Visitor? Tourist? Business? Other?

Comment: Welcome to our confusing visa application website. Please report back if you still have all your hair when you figure out which type you need.

Comment: More seriously, the conference is listed under "cross-border" business. Since your hypothetical traveller is here to attend and not in the context of employment/work I suppose visitor visa is the appropriate type in this case. Have you contacted an embassy near you ?

Comment: @blackbird57 To apply for an eTA as a Brit, [you practically need a thesaurus](https://insideflyer.co.uk/2016/03/flying-canada-need-eta-thesaurus/) as every dropdown has a different country it wants you to give, several times the wrong form / grammatically incorrect / etc....

Comment: If Schengen is any clue - Business visas are for those visiting specifically for the purposes of conducting _business_ (such as signing contracts). All other things come under visit. I have yet to be asked to apply for a business visa when attending conferences in EU.

Comment: We hope you enjoy your time in the colonies, we have your queen on our money ;)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid how could Schengen be a clue when there's no such thing as a business visa in the Schengen system?  Excepting airport transit and national long-stay visas, there's only a short-stay visa, which can be granted for any of several purposes, including for business visits.  This may explain why you haven't been asked to apply for a business visa.

Comment: Ah you are right - what I meant to say was for business purposes - conferences are not listed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Canada does indeed have one of the most confusing web sites I've ever seen.

So, here is the very simple about Canada's visitor visas: **They're all the same.**

Canada refers to all visitor visas, including for tourism, business, and even [transit](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/transit-apply-how.asp), as *temporary resident visas*. [They all use the same application form](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/business-info.asp) and are [good for both business and tourism](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=456&top=16).

> If your visitor is from a [country whose citizens need a visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) to visit Canada, he or she must apply for a temporary resident visa just like any other temporary visitor to Canada. **There is no separate application for business visitors.** The temporary resident visa covers all visitors, including those in Canada on business.

The [application guide](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/guides/5256ETOC.asp) goes into a little more detail, and should be read in its entirety if you are planning to obtain a visa to visit Canada.