# Can I have my flight tickets reimbursed when traveling to South Africa on a tourist visa?

Tags: visas, legal, indian-citizens, south-africa

This question came in -part due to this [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68641/tourist-visa-or-conference-business-visa-for-south-africa). I'll be traveling to South Africa for an open-source conference for which I'll get my flight-tickets reimbursed at the end of the conference. Could/Would this reimbursement be in anyway equated to remuneration ?

http://www.vfsglobal.com/southafrica/india/conferences.html

Common-sense/logic says that should not be so, as remuneration is for doing some work but in this case I would just be an attendee. I will be doing some volunteering but that is not tied in anyways with the travel sponsorship that I'll receive at the end of the conference.

Comment: Who will reimburse your expenses, and why did they choose to do so? There's a difference (at least to some countries' authorities) between "my employer back home is paying for my trip, to keep my skills up-to-date" and "I won a disadvantaged-student participantion grant from the organizers" and "the organizers pay my travel because I'm a speaker at one of the sessions".

Comment: This answer is going to be specfic to SA laws. In many countries, even being paid a speaker's fee is  permissable, provided the fee is only for speaking, and isn't a regular thing.

Comment: Probably because I had asked for it and had been contributing to the specific Open Source platform for number of years in a variety of ways. i'll be mentioning my open-source contributions in a cover letter, would that be ok.

Answer (score 3):

This could be counted as expenses paid (as part of a scholarship).

I attend conferences where some attendees are financially supported because they are from a minority - this doesn't count as payment or remuneration.

It is most important that you mention this clearly in your application so there is not confusion.

Comment: I did the application, got the visa, about to travel... while I can't assume why they financially supported me, either because I'm a minority (in the grander scheme of things) or something else, would like to know what to do next since I didn't mention this in my application.