# Does an Indian seeking a Canadian temporary resident visa need to provide biometric fingerprints?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada, applications

I saw [Can you go to a Conference in Canada on a Visitor Visa, or only a Business one?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65542/can-you-go-to-a-conference-in-canada-on-a-visitor-visa-or-only-a-business-one) and visted: [Canada Temporary Resident Visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/guides/5256ETOC.asp). For biometrics they gave a link which is broken: `10.24.221.62:8080/english/visit/biometrics.asp`. Doing a quick search on http://isup.me/10.24.221.62 and http://isup.me/10.24.221.62:8080 both result in the link being down.

Any other way to know if Indians looking for temporary resident visa need to give biometric fingerprints?

Comment: This seems to be the link you're looking for: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/biometrics.asp

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @GregHewgill maybe convert into an answer

Comment: Serves them well. This is what you get when you employ cheap labour !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the link to the biometrics page from the application guide page is currently broken. IP addresses starting with `10.` are not valid on the public Internet (that range is reserved for private networks), and in any case it is unusual to see a site with only an IP address and no domain name.

It seemed reasonable to me that the biometrics page would be on the same web server as the application guide. So I replaced the server part (`10.24.221.62:8080` of the broken link with `www.cic.gc.ca`) and got the following link, which works:

> http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/biometrics.asp

Comment: I knew/know about 10.x.x.x being on private and hence was surprised as well. Thank you for the pointer though.